How can we distingiush and validate phone numbers of north american countries in javaScript?
I wanted to validate only US and Canadian phone numbers in frontend form.
I worked with reactphonenumberinput but it was allowing all north american countries as they are differntiated by area codes only,instead of country codes(since all have +1 as country code).Are there any prebuilt library or alternative to validate US and Canadian numbers only, by checking the area codes in frontend?Could someone help me?
